# Add folder files to listbox by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, file

I use the below code to get files with different extensions in the folder by LINQ, but no file is found.

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\TextDocument\\");
var filteredFiles = (from fileDir in dirInfo.GetFiles()
                        where (fileDir.Extension == "*.jpg" || fileDir.Extension == "*.rtf")
                        select fileDir).ToList();

foreach (var item in filteredFiles)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I get `filteredFiles.count = 0` in the `foreach` loop. What's wrong in this code?

Comment: `filteredFiles.count = 0`. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try remove `*` from `*.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with,

```
List<System.IO.FileInfo> oFileInfoList = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + "\\TextDocument\\").GetFiles().Where(o => o.Extension == ".jpg" || o.Extension == ".rtf").ToList<System.IO.FileInfo>();
```

FileInfo.Extension have extension without `*` i.e. .jpg, .png, .pdf

Hope It should Help.